# Installation errors - Windows 8.1 features like .NET3.5

Tags: windows-8.1, .net-3.5

I have a program that requires .NET 3.5. When I run it on my Windows 8.1, I get a pop-up saying:

```
An app on your PC needs the following Windows feature:
.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
[Download and install the feature]
```

The "Download" link starts installation, which fails with `Error code: 0x800F0906`, and a [link to generic-style advice like "check your Internet connection"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782). I also tried:

- Installing from `Windows Features` dialog, but got the same error.
- Downloading and running [dotnetfx35.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) - got redirected to the above and failed with the same error.

Following [Corrupted Flash Update prevents Windows Update - DISM fails 0x800f0906](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/corrupted-flash-update-prevents-windows-update/e920a6b8-7a18-4c09-901f-51a8963b9990), I tried running `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`, but neither fixed the issue or produced intelligible logs.

So, how do I install .NET 3.5 on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

Following output from `sfc`, I turned to read `c:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`. At the time of failure, I saw the following lines:

```
Failed to find package: Package_78_for_KB2966828~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.4 from the index with mapping index packages recently rebuilt,  [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
Failed to get WU category/updateID for package: Package_78_for_KB2966828~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.4 [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
Failed to get the category and update ID for package: Package_78_for_KB2966828~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.4, component: amd64_microsoft-windows-wpfcorecomp.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.20708_en-us_a3b67b207d2057ab, file: PresentationHostDLL.dll.mui [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
Exec: Missing files are found during staging attempt but failed to download content from WU. [HRESULT = 0x800f090d - CBS_E_MISSING_PACKAGE_MAPPING_INDEX]
```

On a hunch, I uninstalled `KB2966828` mentioned in the log, and voilà - installation works! I hope Windows Update will install it again if it's really important...

Comment: The reason the `DISM` tool didn't fix the problem is because the actual component appears to have been missing. Really the only thing the command you ran does is verifies the components in the `WinSxS` directory are not corrupt.  Likewise the `sfc` tool compares those components in the `WinSxS` directory to your system components.  It also appears it attempted to download the missing data but wasn't able to.  This can be solved by using the DISM tool against local `WinSxS` source ( i.e. an installation disk ) this way you don't have to worry about not being able to download the content.